# Can an Indian-Bangladeshi married couple go to France together from India?

Tags: indian-citizens, bangladeshi-citizens

That is the question, and allow me to share:

1. Recently married; we have a marriage certificate.
2. She has a valid Bangladeshi passport.
3. I have a valid Indian passport and I went to France once for 2 months.

I will get 2,000 euro per month in France. I hope that is sufficient for the two of us. I will be PhD student for 3 years there.

Comment: Yes why not. Apply for the appropriate visas and if you fulfil all the conditions there is no reason you can’t.

Comment: This question is not about travel, as intended in this site (tourism). You should ask to ex-pat, and eventually to your university.

Comment: What visa are you on in India?

Comment: My wife is now in India on her tourist visa, I am Indian, why would I need a visa to stay in India?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter which country you both are from as long as you satisfy the visa requirements to move to France. Of course, your visa application should be a student visa with you as the primary applicant. I don't think there are any special forms you need to submit since your wife is from Bangladesh.